# Custom Ribbon Button with javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin

Hi i'm working  on a sharepoint Addin i wanna create a custom ribbon button using javascript ,
i tryed with xml it's work fine using this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="e3ae8fc7-7989-467c-ba5f-6bdb1d5064c3.AzeoFullDownload"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="101"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="Invoke &apos;AzeoFullDownload&apos; action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <!-- 
      Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
      that you want to enable for the custom action.
      -->
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.AzeoFullDownloadButton"
                  Alt="AzeoFullDownload"
                  Sequence="100"
                  Command="Invoke_AzeoFullDownloadButtonRequest"
                  LabelText="AzeoFullDownload"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  Image32by32="images/Button-Download.png"
                  Image16by16="images/Button-Download.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_AzeoFullDownloadButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}"
                          EnabledScript="javascript:EnableCopyLinkToClipboard();"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
  </CustomAction>
<!-- 
  <CustomAction
 Id="CopyLinkToClipboardScript"
 Location="ScriptLink"
 ScriptSrc ="~appWebUrl/Pages/App.js"/>  -->
</Elements>
```

thank you

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: my question is how can i create a Custom Ribbon Button for sharepoint addin with javascript

Comment: Why do you want to create the button through JS? You can add it as a module along with your Add-in and then control whether it's enabled or disabled through JS.

Comment: yeah , but i don't want the button directly when i deploy the the add-in ,i wanna call a js fonction to add it

Comment: has any one a solution for this?

Comment: Typically facing the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Actually, your goal is not to create the button with JS, but to control the visibility of the button with JS!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment, you should keep your Xml definition.

you can control the visibility of the button from JS using the `QueryCommand` attribute of the button. This command will allow you to control from a JS component if the button is visible or not.

Take a look at [Sample code: Asynchronously checking if a Ribbon command is available](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sample-code-asynchronously-checking-ribbon-command/).

As an example, in a project I managed I had :

```
 <MRUSplitButton
            Id="MyCorp.Intranet.Publishing.Ribbon.MyAction.MyButton"
            Sequence="10"
            Alt="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
            InitialItem="Mycorp.Intranet.Publishing.Ribbon.MyGroup.Menu.MyAction.MyAction"
            MenuAlt="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
            TemplateAlias="OneRow1"
            Command="MyCorp.Intranet.Publishing.Ribbon.MyAction.Command"
            QueryCommand="MyCorp.Intranet.Publishing.Ribbon.MyAction.Query">
```

And in my js component :

```
handleCommand: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {

    switch (commandId) {
        case 'MyCorp.Intranet.Publishing.Ribbon.MyAction.Query':
            return true; // Or false, depending on your logic
    }
}
```

Hopefully, you have yet implemented custom JS component. Otherwise, prepare for a big headache.